# How can I show multiple counts in one SQL JOIN Query

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I would like to return a table that shows "Client Name, Properties(count), Tenants(count), Permits"(count). Each client has properties. Each Property has tenants and each tenant has permits. I can return how many properties per client with.

```
select cli.Client_Name, count(prop.Client_ID ) as Properties
from profile_Client as CLI
  left join profile_property as Prop on CLI.id = prop.Client_ID 
group by cli.Client_Name
order by cli.Client_Name
```

But from there I'm stuck. Can't figure out how to return how many tenants per property and how many permits per tenant. Ideally a table would look like.

```
   Client   |   Properties   |   Tenants   |   Permits   |
Client 1    |212             |4023         |12203        |
Client 2    |162             |2032         |7203         |
```

Comment: Use `case` expressions to do _conditional aggregation_.

Comment: On a side note: When asking a question on SQL, you should always tag your reuest with the DBMS you are using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach in this situation is to join all tables and count distinct IDs:

```
select
  cli.client_name, 
  count(distinct prop.property_id) as properties,
  count(distinct ten.tenant_id) as tenants,
  count(distinct perm.permit_id) as permits
from profile_client as cli
left join profile_property prop on cli.id = prop.client_id
left join profile_tenant ten on ten.property_id = prop.property_id
left join profile_permit perm on perm.tenant_id = ten.tenant_id
group by cli.client_name
order by cli.client_name;
```

Comment: Got it. I was counting the different ID's but was using DISTINCT. I'll remember to tag properly next time. Thanks.

Comment: @Thorsten . . . `permits` does not require` count(distinct)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please COUNT() OVER(PARTITION BY col1,col2, ORDER BY col1,col2). You havent mentioned full table structure but here is an example of how to get count from your SQL for every hierarchy.
`SELECT * from (
select cli.Client_Name, 
count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY prop.Client_ID ORDER BY prop.Client_ID) as cnt_Properties,
count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY prop.tenant_id,  prop.Client_ID ORDER BY  prop.tenant_id,prop.Client_ID) as cnt_Tenant,
count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Permits  ,prop.tenant_id,  prop.Client_ID ORDER BY  Permits   ,prop.tenant_id,prop.Client_ID) as cnt_Permits,
row_number (*) OVER (PARTITION BY prop.Client_ID ORDER BY prop.Client_ID) as rn
from profile_Client as CLI
  left join profile_property as Prop on CLI.id = prop.Client_ID 
)rs WHERE rs.rn=1
order by cli.Client_Name`